# How do I send shipping info to Paypal via Node.js with paypal-rest-sdk module?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I was wondering how do I send shipment info to Paypal so that when the user gets redirected to Paypal for payment, the user doesn't have to fill out Shipping information again. The user already filled out shipping information and the data is stored in my database. The issue is that the shipping info stored in the database will more than likely not be the same address as the person making the order. The user will more than likely be using another shipping address, not their own. Now I can operate just fine this way but I was thinking: If I dont have the correct shipping address stored on Paypal's records, the customer could easily say I never shipped their product and demand a refund. At this point, I would only have the tracking # to the address stored on my database, not on Paypal's records, thus making me vulnerable to these kind of paypal scams. Correct me if Im wrong anybody.

Below is Paypals example on what data is sent to them during ordering process:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/order/create.js

> ```
> var create_payment_json = {
>     "intent": "order",
>     "payer": {
>         "payment_method": "paypal"
>     },
>     "redirect_urls": {
>         "return_url": "http://return.url",
>         "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
>     },
>     "transactions": [{
>         "item_list": {
>             "items": [{
>                 "name": "item",
>                 "sku": "item",
>                 "price": "1.00",
>                 "currency": "USD",
>                 "quantity": 1
>             }]
>         },
>         "amount": {
>             "currency": "USD",
>             "total": "1.00"
>         },
>         "description": "This is the payment description."
>     }]
> };
> ```
>
> I added a shipping object, see the sample below.
>
> ```
>     var create_payment_json = {
>       "intent": "sale",
>       "payer": {
>           "payment_method": "paypal"
>       },
>       "redirect_urls": {
>           "return_url": "https://website.com/thankyou",
>           "cancel_url": "https://website.com"
>       },
>       "transactions": [{
>           "item_list": {
>               "items": [{
>                   "name": name,
>                   "sku": "item",
>                   "price": total_price,
>                   "currency": "USD",
>                   "quantity": 1
>               }]
>           },
>           "shipping_address": {
>             "recipient_name":recipient_name,
>             "line1":line_1,
>             "city": city,
>             "state":state,
>             "postal_code":zipcode,
>             "country_code":"US"
>           },
>           "amount": {
>               "currency": "USD",
>               "total": total_price
>           },
>           "description": description
>       }]
>       };
> ```

But I get this error:

```
"response": {
    "name":"MALFORMED REQUEST",
    "message":"Incoming JSON request",
    "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "debug_id":"cb2ecc213218b",
    "httpStatusCode":400
},
"httpStatusCode":400
}
```

I didn't just make this up the shipping object. On a successful Paypal payment, PayPal returns a transaction object that includes the shipping address object. I copied exactly the way I saw it, assuming I could send the shipping info to Paypal.

How can I send shipping info to Paypal via REST API / node.js when creating a Paypal order. Remember, when you checkout at any store and login to Paypal, the shipping address is automatically your shipping address that you set with Paypal. How do I change it via API? If you cant, how do stores typically handle these kinds of situations? For example, buy a gift for a friend. Thanks for your time, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You have the right approach. The `shipping_address` object belongs inside the `item_list` next to the `items` array.

An example here:

```
var create_payment_json = {
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
      "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "redirect_urls": {
      "return_url": "https://website.com/thankyou",
      "cancel_url": "https://website.com"
  },
  "transactions": [{
      "item_list": {
          "shipping_address": {
              "recipient_name":recipient_name,
              "line1":line_1,
              "city": city,
              "state":state,
              "postal_code":zipcode,
              "country_code":"US"
          },
          "items": [{
              "name": name,
              "sku": "item",
              "price": total_price,
              "currency": "USD",
              "quantity": 1
          }]
      },
      "amount": {
          "currency": "USD",
          "total": total_price
      },
      "description": description
  }]
  };
```

Comment: Uwe Wiemer how do i remove shipping completely from my transactions?